# Google Search Console and Sitemap set-up for a website subfolder

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I'm managing a website https://www.example.com/ and I've just launched a new website https://www.example.com/talkabout (so with a subfolder).

I've already set up a GSC account, sitemaps (html and XML), robots.txt for the root domain but was wondering if I need to set them up for https://www.example.com/talkabout?

I believe the robots.txt of the "/talkabout" site should be the same as the root domain one (https://www.example.com/robots.txt) but should I set up a separate GSC account and an XML sitemap e.g https://www.example.com/talkabout/sitemap.xml and add it on the robots.txt?

Comment: AFAIK you _can't_ set up a separate GSC account for a website that is a subfolder of a domain.

Comment: It's what I thought, thanks for the confirmation though.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to set up a new account for a sub folder. It will be seen as the same site but with a new folder. If you create a new page in the 'talkabout' folder then try to inspect it in GSC it should show up and prove you don't need a new account.

If however, you made a new **sub domain** on https://www.example.com then you should create a new GSC account and sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a different XML sitemap set up for your folder and it won't confuse the search engines. [Source.](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location)

Just keep in mind that they are properly linked to from the main sitemap.

But when it comes to GSC or Analytics for that matter, that is not possible to implement it on folders.